# php assosiate array through foreach

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

i am having database table in Microsoft access which has field  as follows:
partno,description,quantity

when i am retriving data and trying to show it in html table it shows error

> Illegal string offset 'partno'

my php code is as follows:

```
<?php
 foreach($items as $row){
    $partno=$row['partno'];
    $desc=$row['description'];
    $qty=$row['quantity'];
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?=$partno?></td>
  <td><?=$desc?></td>
  <td><?=$qty?></td>
  </tr>

  <?php  
    }
    }
    if(!($items)){
  ?>
  <h3 style="color: red;">Item not found!</h3>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
```

i tried see data through

```
print_r($items);
```

data of array $items is :

```
Array ( 
    [partno] => BRZU 
    [0] => BRZU 
    [description] => CONTROL UNIT 
    [1] => CONTROL UNIT 
    [quantity] => 3 
    [2] => 3 
)
```

Comment: Add the code with which you retrive data to get more help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `$items` actually contains just a single row.
Using a foreach loop over it will cause `$row` to assume values `BZRU, BZRU, CONTROL UNIT, 2, 3`.

I think that you were expecting an array of arrays like this, over which you can iterate with your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Verify first that the array `items` is not empty before proceeding with the loop.

```
<?php
     if(is_array($items) && count($items) > 0){//check that we have something before proceeding with the loop
       foreach($items as $row){
        $partno=$row['partno'];
        $desc=$row['description'];
        $qty=$row['quantity'];
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?=$partno?></td>
      <td><?=$desc?></td>
      <td><?=$qty?></td>
      </tr>

      <?php  
        }
      } else {
          ?>
      <h3 style="color: red;">Item not found!</h3>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect. You need to check if `$items` is empty before attempting to iterating through it.